# How to use PFRelation for liking?

Tags: swift, parse-platform, pfrelation

I want to make a social media app where you can like posts and I heard that you can use PFRelation to do that, but I'm not sure how. I checked Parse.com's docs but it gave me limited information on it, so how would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on what you want to make it a relation to. Is it users? Is it a post class itself? Is it statistics class (i.e. Number of views, number of likes, active comments)? If you want to create a like feature, for simplicity, I would forego creating an entire relation if that's the only feature you are worried about. Simply create a new column in the backend and increment it every time the user taps on like, and decrease it when they re-tap.

Let's say you have a Class called Posts. And in Posts you have these columns:

| objectId | PostTitle (string) | PostDesc (string) | PostImage (File) | Likes (number) | updatedAt | createdAt | etc etc

All you would need to do is when a user taps on the like button increment the 'Like' column by 1, and vice versa

If your worried about relations for other reasons than I understand. But this is a suitable avenue to take for something so simple

---

```
someObject.incrementKey("Likes")
someObject.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
(success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
  if (success) {
  // The like key has been incremented
  } else {
  // There was a problem, check error.description
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah I tried to do this, but I couldn't figure it out. By any chance do you have source code of how to do it?

Comment: What would I set my likes label as? And how would I make it so it would save the likes for each post. (Sorry for being a newb)

Comment: @EthanCotler see edit. You will have to do your own research and understand how to do things through Parse. Their documentation is outstanding and should be the first resource you seek. https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/guide#getting-started they have almost every scenario you could think of documented now, even for swift :)

Comment: Ok thanks! Will do. But I just have one question and then I'll accept it as the answer. When I set the label of the amount of likes what should I set it as.. should I do likeLabel.text = someObject.incrementKey("Likes")?

Comment: SO is assuming you have some basic understanding of the issue you post. You should show that you have given effort in trying things yourself before posting by providing code you've tried. If you don't feel comfortable with swift/parse, that's fine too. Nothing wrong with being new, we all start somewhere. But it's how you learn that makes a difference. You can't learn much if people spell everything out for you. I'm almost positive there are tutorials out there that can assist you, this answer was to address a particular instance, not _all_ your instances

Comment: Yeah you're right I've just been looking for hours to find out how to do this. I've basically looked everywhere. But yeah thanks for helping out! (:

Comment: @EthanCotler check this out. This should help out a lot http://www.appcoda.com/instagram-app-parse-swift/

Comment: Thanks for all of your help. I will check both of those out.

Comment: @EthanCotler great. Give it a try after reading the parse documents and going through a few tutorials. If after that it ain't working out for you come back and let me know I'll get you straight

Comment: The second tutorial goes through the process pretty smoothly for addin a vote or like option. Look for : Upping The Ante: Instagram Like Function section @EthanCotler you shouldn't need me after that

Comment: Ok thanks again for all of your help!

Comment: I've been doing this tutorial and I tried to run it and I got a match linker error and it also said... library not found for -lBolts

Comment: Wait nvm I figured it out. Sorry for the confusion